# What is difference between Binance Smart Chain and Ethereum network?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, binance-smart-chain

I want to create a bsc( binance smart chain) but strangely, In official documentation, they create a network by geth only. then I was really confused. What is difference between bsc and ethereum network? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a bsc( binance smart chain) but strangely, In official documentation, they create a network by geth only. then I was really confused. What is difference between bsc and ethereum network?

Binance Smart Chain [forked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)) GoEthereum (geth) software developed by Ethereum Foundation and many volunteers. This can be considered a hostile fork, as Binance does not seem to contribute back to the original geth, does not support geth maintenance or does not support any of the development communities (web3.js, web3.py, etc.)

Binance changed some geth parameters from the Ethereum mainnet, like block size. Also the transaction fees are artificially kept low, causing [the network being unstable and hard to use for developers](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1463454127095042050). Thus, BSC does not achieve any of decentralised qualities of blockchains.

Binance and Ethereum Foundation do not co-operate.

Most of the Ethereum software develop tools are compatible with Binance Smart Chain, as the EVM virtual machine is pretty much same (Binance has not done none of innovation or enhancements, the official statement of "significant changes" is questionable.) However, support for Binance Smart Chain is way worse, as Binance do not have active developer community and most of the Binance Smart Chain developers leech their information out from Ethereum support forums.

Answer (score 3):

According to Binance's official faq:

> Binance Smart Chain (BSC) is a hard fork of the Go Ethereum (Geth)
> protocol, and as such, shares many similarities with the Ethereum
> blockchain. However, BSC developers have made significant changes in
> some key areas. The largest change is BSC's consensus mechanism, which
> allows for cheaper and faster transactions.

**Source:** https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/binance-smart-chain-vs-ethereum-what-s-the-difference